# Meteor 1.5.2 ios simulator issue, typeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: xcode, meteor, ios-simulator, meteor-ios

I’m on Xcode 8.3.3 with OS X 10.12.6

Fresh install of meteor 15.2.

Basically, i just created a basic app using meteor create 
It prompted me to update to meteor 1.5.2 and I updated though it worked fine for meteor 1.4.3.
When I tried running meteor run ios after adding platforms for both the versions, it gave me the below error for 1.5.2

meteor run ios gives error.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:

While running Cordova app for platform iOS with options --emulator:

> Error: Command failed:
>   /Users/{$USER}/Development/webdev/simple-todos-react/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/run
>   --emulator TypeError: Cannot read property ‘replace’ of undefined at remove
>   (/Users/{$USER}/Development/webdev/simple-todos-react/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/ios-sim/src/lib.js:282:70)
>   at Array.forEach (native) at Object.lib.getdevicetypes
>   (/Users/{$USER}/Development/webdev/simple-todos-react/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/ios-sim/src/lib.js:292:22)
>   at Object.listEmulatorImages [as run]
>   (/Users/{$USER}/Development/webdev/simple-todos-react/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/list-emulator-images:34:29)
>   at deployToSim
>   (/Users/{$USER}/Development/webdev/simple-todos-react/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/run.js:173:50)
>   at
>   /Users/{$USER}/Development/webdev/simple-todos-react/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/run.js:115:20
>   at _fulfilled
>   (/Users/{$USER}/Development/webdev/simple-todos-react/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
>   at self.promiseDispatch.done
>   (/Users/{$USER}/Development/webdev/simple-todos-react/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
>   at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch
>   (/Users/{$USER}/Development/webdev/simple-todos-react/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
>   at
>   /Users/{$USER}/Development/webdev/simple-todos-react/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
>   at ChildProcess.exitCallback (/tools/utils/processes.js:151:23) at
>   emitTwo (events.js:87:13) at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7) at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:12)
>   => awaited here: at Function.Promise.await (/Users/{$USER}/.meteor/packages/templating-compiler/.1.3.2.qn524o++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileTemplatesBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:35:12)
>   at CordovaProject.runCommands (/tools/cordova/project.js:715:22) at
>   CordovaProject.run$ (/tools/cordova/project.js:261:10) at tryCatch
>   (/Users/{$USER}/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2.9i7mdi++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
>   at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke]
>   (/Users/{$USER}/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2.9i7mdi++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:337:22) at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next]
>   (/Users/{$USER}/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2.9i7mdi++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:96:21)
>   at tryCatch
>   (/Users/{$USER}/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2.9i7mdi++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
>   at invoke
>   (/Users/{$USER}/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2.9i7mdi++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:139:20) at
>   /Users/{$USER}/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2.9i7mdi++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:184:11
>   at callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
>   (/Users/{$USER}/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2.9i7mdi++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:183:16) at AsyncIterator.enqueue
>   (/Users/{$USER}/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2.9i7mdi++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:206:13) at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next]
>   (/Users/{$USER}/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2.9i7mdi++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:96:21)
>   at Object.runtime.async
>   (/Users/{$USER}/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2.9i7mdi++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:226:14) at
>   /Users/{$USER}/.meteor/packages/templating-compiler/.1.3.2.qn524o++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileTemplatesBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:32:39
>
> /Users/{$USER}/.meteor/packages/templating-compiler/.1.3.2.qn524o++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileTemplatesBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:190
>   throw error; ^ undefined
>   => awaited here: at Function.Promise.await (/Users/{$USER}/.meteor/packages/templating-compiler/.1.3.2.qn524o++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileTemplatesBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:35:12)
>   at /tools/cordova/runner.js:98:17 at
>   /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:271:13 at [object
>   Object]..extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14) at
>   /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:264:29 at [object
>   Object]..extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14) at
>   /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:262:18 at [object
>   Object]..extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14) at
>   /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:253:23 at [object
>   Object]..extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14) at
>   Object.capture (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:252:19) at
>   CordovaRunner.startRunTargets (/tools/cordova/runner.js:97:37) at
>   [object Object]._.extend.runOnce (/tools/runners/run-app.js:772:21) at
>   [object Object]..extend._fiber (/tools/runners/run-app.js:885:28) at
>   /tools/runners/run-app.js:412:12
>
> cat .meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/VERSION gives
>   me 4.4.0

so the api is deprecated on iOS 9.0 api

what’s the proper way to update cordova to the latest version to work with iOS 10 (and potentially iOS 11 weeks later)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (or was) a bug in the ios-sim package that Meteor uses to run the iOS Simulator. Until this dependency is updated in Meteor, you can work around the problem by manually updating ios-sim in your project folder, this should work:

```
cd .meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova
meteor npm install ios-sim@latest
```

you can check out klaussner's answer here on github issueb below:

> https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/9098